# PASAR CONTENIDO DE UNA VARIABLE DE JAVASCRIPT A UNA VARIABLE DE PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

[image]

Necesito ayuda con esto, como puedo hacer para obtener el valor de una ventana de JavaScript y actualizar dicho valor en la base de datos, hasta ahora tengo el código así que pensé que funcionaria pero el valor no se actualiza en la base de datos.

Comment: Lo que necesitas es leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] porque poner una imagen del código no te va a dar las soluciones que esperas conseguir. UNA IMAGEN DEL CÓDIGO NO ES VÁLIDA. Y obviamente, php se ejecuta en tu servidor y javascript en tu navegador, son dos procesos diferentes incluso aunque ambos estén en el mismo PC, con lo cual nunca funcionará así. Si quieres pasarle información desde JS a PHP, necesitas una llamada asíncrona por ejemplo con la [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) o con ajax o lo que te sea más cómodo

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme, uffff fuiste de gran ayuda, pongo el código porque es lo que tengo y quería saber dónde estaba el error o que es lo que me falta pero enserio me ayudaste demasiado.